# How much disk space is expected to take an osm2pgsql import of Europe in 2021?

Tags: osm2pgsql, europe

My europe-latest.osm.pbf file is 24GB. I'm currently importing it on 8-core 32GB-RAM server with `osm2pgsql` as part of `switch2osm`. I've run the default docker container of `switch2osm` and after 2 days, the docker volume took more than 400GB of disk space and it kept going.

The `top` cli command shows that `osm2pgsql` is still actively running. Is it normal to take up so much space? I've read a post from 2018 where a guy claims that his `osm2pgsql` import took between 170GB and 240GB of disk space. My machine has ~ 600GB of free space.

- Should I worry that it might not have enough disk space?
- How long is normal to take for the whole procedure with a default `switch2osm` configuration?

Comment: crossspot: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/80623/about-how-much-disk-space-is-expected-to-take-an-osm2pgsql-import-of-europe-in-2021

Answer (score 1):

The osm2pgsql import of Europe took ~500GB disk space running it with `--flat-nodes` flag. But I believe it's too much and I do something wrong.

Comment: I am currently running the same issue importing the europe file. I have 1TB SSD disk almost filed up.